# How to avoid blank data spaces when using pandas df.value_counts()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When using the pandas library to interpret a dataset I am trying to sum up all the pairs across 2 columns of the dataframe by using value_counts(subset = ...). Unfortunately it keeps giving me spaces in the results that shouldn't be there and make the output unreadable. Anyone know how to avoid this?

Attempted:

clm = [
'class', 'cap-shape', 'cap-surface', 'cap-color', 'bruises?', 'odor',
'gill-attachment', 'gill-spacing', 'gill-size', 'gill-color', 'stalk-shape',
'stalk-root', 'stalk-surface-above-ring', 'stalk-surface-below-ring',
'stalk-color-above-ring', 'stalk-color-below-ring', 'veil-type',
'veil-color', 'ring-number', 'ring-type', 'spore-print-color', 'population',
'habitat'
]

```
myTable = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, names=clm)

print(myTable.value_counts(subset = ['class', 'cap-color']))
```

Result:

[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdyWd.png)

There shouldn't be any blank spaces, each row should have a 'p' or an 'e'

Comment: You can add dropna=False

Comment: myTable.value_counts(subset = ['class', 'cap-color']).reset_index()

Comment: dropna=False does not change the result at all.

Comment: reset_index() worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the value_counts() set the parameter normalize=False

```
myTable.value_counts(subset=['class', 'cap-color'], normalize=False)
```